# Wrap the content of a flex column around another flex column

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I'd like the CONTENT flex column to wrap around the left-hand rowChild592 column.

I have this:

[image]

I'd like it to look something like this:

[image]

I saw an answer here about making a div set to a table cell wrap around:

- [Wrapping table content around a floating div across multiple rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39499871/wrapping-table-content-around-a-floating-div-across-multiple-rows)

Would I have to redo all of this with a table, or is it possible to wrap a flex column around another?

```css
.rowParent,
.columnParent {
  display: flex;
}

.columnParent {
  flex-direction: column;
}

.flexChild {
  flex: 1;
}

#flexymenu {
  flex-grow: 2;
  height: 100%;
}

.frame {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.socialwrap {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div id="container" class="flexChild rowParent">
  <div id="rowChild592" class="flexChild">
    <h1></h1>
    <div class="socialwrap"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="flexymenu" class="flexChild columnParent">
    <div id="columnChild85412" class="flexChild rowParent">
      <div id="rowChild97758" class="flexChild"></div>
      <div id="rowChild52237" class="flexChild"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="columnChild59385" class="flexChild selected">
      <div class="frame">CONTENT</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Flexbox is not designed for wrapping elements around other elements. It can only align elements along columns or rows. Here's a more complete explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34481128/3597276

Comment: @Michael_B thanks for the explanation! Could grid do this?

Answer (score 1):

In [**flex layout**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/), elements can be aligned along columns *or* rows. A flex item cannot span between both columns and rows, which could allow the content of one item to wrap around another item. So, flexbox is not a good option for achieving your layout. [Read more.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34480760/3597276)

In [**grid layout**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/), elements can span across columns *and* rows. A grid item can be configured to take up as many rows and columns as desired, which would allow for the content of one item to wrap around other items, *except* for one limitation currently in place: *The grid area must be rectangular*.

This behavior is defined in two parts of the spec.

> [**9. Placing Grid
>   Items**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#placement)
>
> Every grid item has a grid area, a rectangular set of grid cells that
>   the grid item occupies.

---

> [**7.3. Named Areas: `the grid-template-areas`
>   property**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#grid-template-areas-property)
>
> If a named grid area spans multiple grid cells, but those cells do not
>   form a single filled-in rectangle, the declaration is invalid.
>
> Note: Non-rectangular or disconnected regions may be permitted in a
>   future version of this module.

---

So, for the foreseeable future, tetris-shaped grid areas are not possible, which would make your layout simple and easy.

To wrap your text around images, stick to the good ol' [**`float`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float?v=example) property. After all, this is exactly what it was designed to do.

And if you're thinking about using `float` inside a flex or grid container, it won't work. Floats are ignored in both a [*flex formatting context*](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-containers) and [*grid formatting context*](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#grid-containers).

Comment: Thanks, that's really helpful to clear up my understanding! I'm trying to work out if border-images that "tetris" along with the shape of the element would work with floating the element like this?

Comment: That brings in another problem. You should post a new question with a focus on border images and floats so it can get full attention.

Comment: Is this answer still relevant now? I'm guessing yes...